# Using a pointer to my arrays gives me an "Unhandled exception" in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, visual-c++

Here's the full code for reference:

```
#include <SDL.h>            /* SDL stuff */
#include <SDL_video.h>      /* surfaces,screen,renderer */
#include <SDL_keyboard.h>   /* to handle kbd input */
#include <cstdlib>          /*srand,rand*/
#include <iostream>         /* cout,cin */
#include <time.h>           /* time */

#define NUMFLAKES 128
#define NUMLOOPS (NUMFLAKES >> 1)

//setup the putpixel function
void putpixel( SDL_Renderer* renderer,int &x,int &y,SDL_Color &pxl )
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, pxl.r,pxl.g,pxl.b,pxl.a );
    SDL_RenderDrawPoint( renderer,x,y );
}

int quitFunc( SDL_Surface *screen,SDL_Texture *texdisp,SDL_Renderer *renderer,SDL_Window *window );

int main( int argc,char *args[] )
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio( false ); //make iostream a bit snappier by stopping sync with stdio

        //Start SDL
    int initret = SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS );
    switch( initret ) {
    case true:
    std::cout << "SDL_Init: Couldn't start SDL...\n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl; break;
    default:    break;
    }

    SDL_DisplayMode fulldisp;
    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode( 0,&fulldisp );
    //The attributes of the screen
    const int PX_WIDTH      = (int)(fulldisp.w / 1.5);
    const int PX_HEIGHT     = (int)(fulldisp.h / 1.5);
    int xo[NUMFLAKES] = {};
    int yo[NUMFLAKES] = {};
    int *x = &xo[NUMFLAKES];        //fix this bullshit
    int *y = &yo[NUMFLAKES];


    //To define the current window
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow( "SDL Snowflakes",
                                            SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                            PX_WIDTH,PX_HEIGHT,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    //The surface using the window defined above
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );
    SDL_ShowCursor(1);

    /* Set up renderer */
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window,-1,
                             SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE  | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );
    /* render to texture */
    SDL_Texture* texdisp = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGB888,
                                             SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET,PX_WIDTH,PX_HEIGHT);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget( renderer,texdisp );

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurfaceRects( window,NULL,NUMFLAKES );
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer,0,0,0,0 );
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    //colours for putpixel
    SDL_Color white;
    SDL_Color rndcol;
    white = { 0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF };
    rndcol = { rand() % 255,rand() % 255,rand() % 255,0xFF };

    //If there was an error in setting up the screen
    switch((bool)(screen)) {
    case 0:
        SDL_Quit(); return 1; break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Created window of size: " << PX_WIDTH << "x" << PX_HEIGHT << std::endl;
        break;
    }

    SDL_Event sdlevent;
    SDL_PollEvent( &sdlevent );

    //Setup Snow Flakes
    SDL_Rect        putfr;      //Rect for updating the screen

    int flake = NUMFLAKES;
    int *pFlake = &flake;

    srand( ( unsigned )time( NULL ) );
    for( *pFlake = 0; *pFlake < NUMFLAKES; (*pFlake)++ )
    {
        (*x)[ pFlake ] = rand() % PX_WIDTH;
        (*y)[ pFlake ] = rand() % ( int )( PX_HEIGHT / 1.5 );
        xo[ *pFlake ] = (*x)[ pFlake ];
        yo[ *pFlake ] = (*y)[ pFlake ];

        std::cout << "Set origin..." << (*x)[ pFlake ] << "," << (*y)[ pFlake ]
                  << "\nAt address->" << y[ *pFlake ] << "," << y[ *pFlake ] << std::endl;

        putpixel( renderer,(*x)[ pFlake ],(*y)[ pFlake ],white );

        /* Intended to only update what changed on screen, still working on it, ignore this */
        putfr.x = (*x)[ pFlake ];
        putfr.y = (*y)[ pFlake ];
        SDL_SetRenderTarget( renderer,NULL );
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer,texdisp,NULL,&putfr );
        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );
    }

    int move,movex,movey;
    for( int loop = 0; loop <= NUMLOOPS && (bool)(sdlevent.type != SDL_QUIT); loop++ )
    {
        for( (*pFlake) = 0; (*pFlake) < NUMFLAKES && sdlevent.type != SDL_QUIT; (*pFlake)++,SDL_PollEvent( &sdlevent ) )
        {
            //resetting rndcol
            rndcol = { rand() % 255,rand() % 255,rand() % 255 };

            // choose whether to move left, right or straight down and by how many pixels
            move = rand() % 3;
            movex = ( rand() % 2 ) + 1;
            movey = ( rand() % 5 ) + 1;

            //backup the existing positions
            xo[ *pFlake ] = (*x)[ pFlake ];
            yo[ *pFlake ] = (*y)[ pFlake ];

            // now draw again
            putpixel( renderer,(*x)[ pFlake ],(*y)[ pFlake ],rndcol );

            // move down the screen by the no of movey
            if( (*y)[ pFlake ] + ( movey + 1 ) < PX_HEIGHT )
            {
                (*y)[ pFlake ] = (*y)[ pFlake ] + ( movey + 1 );
            } else {
                putpixel( renderer,(*x)[ pFlake ],(*y)[ pFlake ],rndcol );
                (*y)[ pFlake ] = rand() % ( PX_HEIGHT / 2 );
            }


            if( (*x)[ pFlake ] < 0 ) {
                (*x)[ pFlake ] = movex;
            }

            if( (*x)[ pFlake ] > PX_WIDTH ) {
                (*x)[ pFlake ] = ( PX_WIDTH - movex );
            }

            // if 0 then left, 1 for right, else straight down
            switch( move ) {
            case 0:
                (*x)[ &pFlake ] = (*x)[ &pFlake ] - movex; break;
            case 1:
                (*x)[ &pFlake ] = (*x)[ &pFlake ] + movex; break;
            }

            putpixel( renderer,(*x)[ pFlake ],(*y)[ pFlake ],rndcol );

        }
        //Renderer needs only to update what changes
        putfr.x = xo[ *pFlake ];
        putfr.y = yo[ *pFlake ];
        SDL_SetRenderTarget( renderer,NULL );
        SDL_RenderCopy( renderer,texdisp,&putfr,&putfr );
        SDL_RenderPresent( renderer );

        SDL_Delay(128);
        //std::cout << "Completed " << loop << " loops" << std::endl;
    }
    quitFunc( screen,texdisp,renderer,window );

    return 0;   //just to stop compiler warning
}

int quitFunc( SDL_Surface *screen,SDL_Texture *texdisp,SDL_Renderer *renderer,SDL_Window *window )
{
    SDL_FreeSurface( screen );      // Destroy things before SDL_Quit
    SDL_DestroyTexture( texdisp );
    SDL_DestroyRenderer( renderer );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    std::cout << "\nDestroyed SDL objects, calling SDL_Quit()..." << std::endl;
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "\nAccomplished SDL_Quit\n" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to use pointers to x[] and y[] (Not an array of pointers, but a pointer to the array) to make the program just use those objects, instead of making copies and changing those.

This is pretty much just to lean toward processing efficiency/minimizing the program footprint, as the arrays could get too big at certain points and copying those might take too much time.

I have also tried:

```
int *x = { &xo[NUMFLAKES] };
int *y = { &yo[NUMFLAKES] };
```

Which gave me the same error. I know that I'm probably using pointers incorrectly (I think it's trying to access the wrong memory?), but I'm unsure of how to do it the *correct* way.

Comment: Can you try boiling this down to more of a minimal example? That alone might clarify the problem for you.

Comment: @sfjac I've tried to do so (In a separate project) but I haven't been able to recreate the error outside of this using code that's a minimal representation of this :/ maybe I should ditch pointers and try to make it efficient elsewhere until I can figure out what's going on?

Comment: If you use vectors and a good debug compiler, it will trigger a breakpoint upon out of bounds access.

Comment: Necroposting 7 years later; Anyone that may see this post, please don't code like this  using raw pointers in user code (any code that doesn't end up in an #include) is always a mistake and should probably be considered a bug in and of itself, but even aside, sit and explain your project to yourself before you start typing, and you'll end up catching yourself before you re-assign a pointer by mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that the issue is

`int *x = &xo[NUMFLAKES];`

This is initializing the pointer x to point to the address of the `NUMFLAKES` element of the array - one past the end of the array. That is not likely what you meant. Perhaps

`int *x = &xo[0]`?

This sets the pointer to the address of the first element of the array, allowing you to use `x` as an alias for `xo`.

Answer (score 3):

The error is here: `int *x = &xo[NUMFLAKES];`
You are trying to access the index 128 (NUMFLAKES) of an array of size 128. This index (128) is out of bound since the index start at 0.

You can achieve what you are looking for with the following:

```
int *p;
int xo[NUMFLAKES];

p = xo; // <-- Now p is pointing to the first element of xO
```